# x-editable, bootstrap and symfony

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I am trying to get x-editable, bootstrap and symfony to work.

I am able to get it somewhat jiving but I am having a heck of a time understanding how to get my json response into a drop down menu. I am all new to this whole jquery, bootstrap and symfony world so go easy on me :)

This is my inline element that I am loading my drop down elements into:

```
<a href="#" id="myElement">Admin</a>
```

Then I am triggering it with this snippet of code:

```
$('#myElement').editable({
        type: 'select',
        value: 2,
        source: '{{ path('product_category_groups') }}'
    });
```

This is the response I get back from ajax:

```
{"responseCode":200,"options":[{"value":0,"text":"Guest"},{"value":1,"text":"Service"},{"value":2,"text":"Customer"},{"value":3,"text":"Operator"},{"value":4,"text":"Support"},{"value":5,"text":"Guest"}]}
```

This is what my drop down box looks like when the json response comes back to the browser(image attached). [image]

I cannot figure out what in the world to do via the documentation on x-editable. There are no working examples anywhere.

Comment: X-editable needs the contents of your `options` array. Is there a possibility to just return that array from your server?

Answer (score 0):

You'll make your own ajax call to your service endpoint and then return the list of options to the source parameter like this:

```
$('#myElement').editable({
        type: 'select',
        value: 2,
        source: function(){
                 var obj; 
                $.get({
                 url: '{{ path('product_category_groups') }}',
                 success: function(resp){obj = resp.options;},
                 async: false,
                 dataType: 'json'
                 });
                 return obj;
        }
    });
```